# Post article to my wordpress blog and app

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, mobile, plugins

I've searched for a plugin but I couldn't find any. Is there a plugin with which I can sync my wordpress website and mobile app.

I want everytime when I post an article to my website the same article to be published and in my already build mobile app(Android and iOS)

Thank You!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Did you try the wordpress app pour [android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wordpress.android&hl=fr) (an [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/wordpress/id335703880?mt=8)) ?

Comment: As far as I know the wordpress app lets me publish articles from my phone. I want to write the articles from the dekstop version of my website and publish them to my app(and website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your own custom Mobile Apps to get new posts from WordPress site, as WordPress does its job by providing RSS feed or JSON data which your APP can use to fetch all new posts into your APP.

You need to talk to your Mobile APP developer and ask them to connect your app to your WordPress site's RSS feed or better JSON Data API.
For RSS Feeds:
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

For JSON API Info:
http://v2.wp-api.org/